# Is T7 promotor leaky in DH5 alpha?

Tags: molecular-biology

In my experiment I found that a GFP gene under T7 promotor in high copy number pTAC-2 vector is showing green fluorescence producing colonies of DH5 alpha under UV light. what could be the possible reason?

Comment: Shouldn't pTAC have the tac promoter and not T7?

Comment: You got a T7 phage contamination?

Comment: Did you eliminate autofluorescent activities?

Comment: Confirm your strain has DE3 or other mutated lacp? Best practice to include selection antibiotic for the lac cassette as well. Also @243 answer above. Finally Check agar for any supplements and run map on plasmid to confirm it is ptac

Answer (score 1):

Consider the phenomenon of zygotic induction, as originally observed by Art Pardee, Francois Jacob, and Jacques Monod (sometimes called the "PaJaMo", or "PaJaMa" experiment): regulation of a repressed promoter can be affected by the copy number of the promoter in the cell. Put another way, if the copy number of the *lac* operator in the cell is high enough to bind or titrate all of the available *lac* repressor protein in the cell, then some of the *lac* promoters in the cell will be expressed.